# Building a "Wrapper" class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to wrap an object inside another one in Java. So if we start with a class A, I essentially need to build a subclass (class B) that takes an instance of class A in the constructor and initialises all it's fields to be the same as those of class A. The idea is that B becomes A, but just adds some extra stuff to it. I'm wondering if there's any way to do this without having to manually assign all the fields (also it's impossible to assign `final` fields this way so that's another thing to consider).

This is my first question ever so I apologise if it's not clear. Please feel free to request clarification if required.

Thanks for any help,

Andrei

Comment: Why do you want a copy of all the field values, instead of just holding a reference to the original instance of A and using its values?  I think you are confusing composition vs inheritance.

Comment: I think you don't understand the meaning of 'superclass'. A is the superclass, B should just extend A.

Comment: If you want to create a wrapper (or decorator), it is 'better' to have a common interface that both A and B implement, than having B extend A.

Comment: You would, probably, get better suggestions if you'd describe what you need that behavior for. As far as I understand, you want to `class B extends A {}` where A has copying constructor (i/e. `public A(A a) {...}` where you need to assign all fields a.* to this.*)  and then call this constructor form copying constructor in B via `super(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change final variables, and you'll have to change the other fields manually. You should really just create another object entirely.

```java
public class A {
    private final int x;
    private int y;

    public A( int x, int y ) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    ...
}

public class B extends A {

    public B( final A a ) {
        super( a.getX(), a.getY() );
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: quite often, you can change final variables, you can't re-reference them.

Comment: You can modify final variables, but you cannot reassign them. I believe he meant reassigning.